# Why does MemoryStream not offer a constructor taking a "long" capacity?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, io, stream

According to [.NET MemoryStream - Should I set the capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609445/net-memorystream-should-i-set-the-capacity), it's preferred to set the initial capacity of a [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.MemoryStream(v=vs.110).aspx) if you know it beforehand.

In my code, I'm receiving (from a third party library) a [Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) object. This `Stream` is wrapped around a `GetObjectResponse` class.

Since this class will be disposed after the transaction is closed, I need to copy the received stream so I can continue using it afterwards.

The `Stream` class exposes a [Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length(v=vs.110).aspx) property to determine the length of the stream, so as an initial step to begin the copying process I started writing:

```
Stream destination = new MemoryStream(response.ResponseStream.Length);
```

But the compiler throws an error, stating that `MemoryStream` does not take a `long` parameter, instead it takes an `int`.

Why would they do this?

If `MemoryStream` extends from `Stream`, this means that it can have a long `Length`. If it can have a `long` size, why can't it take a `long` initial capactiy?

I'm trying to avoid initializing the stream with no capacity, because I want to take advantage of the fact that I know how big the stream is going to be, but the constructor seems to be constraining this wish.

How can I approach this and why does `MemoryStream` cannot take a `long` capacity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MemoryStream` does not support more than about 2GB of data right now. This is a current limitation. It does not have to exist in principle.

This is simply a case of a feature not implemented (yet).

Implementing a bigger stream is difficult on the current CLR which only supports arrays with up to about `int.MaxValue` elements.

Comment: It in principle has to exist.  You can't index the array returned by its GetBuffer() and ToArray() members otherwise, array indices must be less than int.MaxValue.

Comment: Ah, that's true. The limitation is locked into the API surface. Maybe a future CLR fixes the array length limitation, though.